# How to add quote to regex inside freeMarker property

Tags: javascript, java, html, regex, freemarker

I have macro ctrls.textInput that create input type text and I want to add regex pattern attribute that will have quotation mark but it break my template,

I've try:

```
<@ctrls.textInput pattern="[^\\x22'<>]+" required=true maxlength=50 />
```

but `\\x22` is replaced by quotation mark inside html and it break my html, is there a way to add quotation mark into pattern attribute?

I've also tried `\\\\x22` but I end up with `\\x22` in attribute.

Comment: did you try with an html entity? or with  `\\u0022`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte html entitiy work, you can add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This syntax seems to follow in some ways that of XML. To figure a character in XML with its code point, you can use an HTML entity:

```
&#34;
&#x22;
```

Or perhaps:

```
&quot;
```

Comment: FreeMarker doesn't resolve `&...;`-s in string literals. Its expression syntax is similar to JavaScript, not to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean it breaks your HTML? Do you insert the regexp itself into HTML? In that case, whenever you insert something non-HTML into HTLM it needs to be escsaped, like `${someValue?html}`.

Also, you shouldn't double-escape the quotation marks, as `"` is not reserved in regular expressions. So it should be just `pattern="[^\"'<>]+"`.